# Как можно подсчитать количество элементов в массиве?

Tags: c#, массивы

Нужно подсчитать количество элементов в массиве.

Comment: Может вам нужно подсчитать количество определенных элементов? Например, сколько в массиве чисел содержится пятерок?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, судя с вопроса то нет

Comment: @Yaroslav - Какой-то слишком примитивный вопрос. Мне кажется, автор его плохо сформулировал. Но может я ошибаюсь.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, согласен) а что сделаешь, хочешь жить, научись выкручиваться с любой ситуации)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно это сделать двумя способами:

через свойство `Length`

```
array1.Length;
```

через метод `Count()`

```
array1.Count()
```

через метод `Count()` c условием какие элементы считать

```
array1.Count(x => x.Equals(y))
```

Разница между `Length` и `Count()`

`Length` - это свойство объекта массива, и использование его является наиболее эффективным способом определения количества элементов в массиве ([`Length`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_Length) в документации MSDN)

`Count()` - это метод расширения LINQ, который делает то же самое. Он применяется к массивам, потому что массивы являются перечислимыми объектами. Предпочтительно использовать Length, потому что Count (), вероятно, будет более дорогостоящим (документация MSDN по [`Count()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads) для справки)

Comment: Раз уж вы знаете оба - то могли бы описать разницу и объяснить, почему и какое предпочтительнее. Если не знаете - можете например переписать отсюда и из msdn: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6646449/5752652

Comment: @A K, сделал.))

Comment: Вот теперь не стыдно и апвоут поставить.

Comment: @A K, спасибо.)

Comment: у Count есть перегрузка принимающая метод, определяющий какие именно элементы считать

Comment: @ Grundy, можно так: array1.Count(x => x.Equals(y))

Comment: Не, вот так не надо. Это более громоздкая запись для того же самого и нужно всегда предпочитать более простые решения. Не будете же вы лететь из Москвы в Питер через Владивосток, если вам туда не надо.

Comment: @A K, почему?))

Answer (score 2):

У массива есть свойство [`Length`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length?view=netframework-4.7.2), которое возвращает количество элементов в массиве.